# clearTimeout() for setTimeout() in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, cleartimeout

`clearTimeout()` inside `for` loop doesn't work

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    myVar = setTimeout(function(){
        alert("Hello")
    }, 3000);
}
```

Fiddle : [**not working**](http://jsfiddle.net/7qr2fgok/)

Fiddle : [**working**](http://jsfiddle.net/77hf3m7t/)

Please help me to stop `setTimeout()` in first Fiddle.

Answer (score 12):

You'll have to keep a reference to each timeout created in the loop, and then iterate and clear each one, otherwise you're just overwriting the `myVar` with a new timeout without clearing the previous one, and loosing the reference as you go etc.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myVar = []

    $("#myfunction").click(myFunction);
    $("#mystopfunction").click(myStopFunction);

    function myFunction() {
        for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            myVar.push(
                setTimeout(function(){
                    alert("Hello")
                }, 3000)
            );
        }
    }

    function myStopFunction() {
        myVar.forEach(function(timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        });
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/7qr2fgok/1/)

Comment: Exactly what I was going to suggest. The code in the original post overwrites the value of `myVar`, and so only the last timeout is affected by `clearTimeout`.

Comment: Man, you've saved my life :D